# How do I get Google Home Mini to play Apple Music?

Tags: apple-music

My boyfriend recently got me a Google pixel 2 but all of our music is on Apple Music. I downloaded the Apple Music app onto my pixel and have been listening to our music through the app. The free Google home mini just arrived and I need help figuring out how to play Apple Music through the Google Mini. Eventually I will get my music on Google Play but I am teaching a yoga class tomorrow and don't have time to figure how to switch my playlist over.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way! If I connect my phone and the mini solely using Bluetooth then it plays YouTube videos and Apple Music.